# Calling method in second activity

Tags: android

I'm writing a tip app where the user selects a check, and then on the second activity the subtotal is displayed. However, I'm completely lost on how I display my subtotal. I have a getSubtotal() method but I don't know how to call it.

First Activity

```
public class TableListActivity extends Activity {


private ListView mListView;

private TableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_list);

    // Find the ListView, create an adapter that reads our list of checks,
    // and connect the two
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mAdapter = new TableListAdapter(this, DataStore.CHECKS);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent (TableListActivity.this, PayCheckActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PayCheckActivity.Extra_check, arg2);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.table_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            // TODO do stuff here
            Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Second Activity

```
public class PayCheckActivity extends Activity{ 
String Thank;
Button Sign;
Button fifteen;
Button eighteen;
Button twenty;
String sample;

public static final String Extra_check= "abc";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.paycheck);
  Sign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sign);
  fifteen= (Button)findViewById(R.id.fifteen);
  eighteen= (Button)findViewById(R.id.eighteen);
  twenty= (Button)findViewById(R.id.twenty);
  Sign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
  Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             msg.show();
  }});
  fifteen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
  Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Thank Yolllllu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             msg.show();
  }});}}
```

Check.java

```
public class Check {
private long id;
private String tableName;
private ArrayList<MenuItem> mItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
private boolean hasBeenSigned = false;

public static class MenuItem {

    public String name;
    public Amount cost;

    public MenuItem(String itemDescription, double cost) {
        this.name = itemDescription;
        this.cost = new Amount(cost);
    }
}

public Check(long id, String tableName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tableName = tableName;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // The ArrayAdapter uses toString to get the text to display in the list item
    // We override toString here to display the table name
    return tableName;
}

public void addItem(String itemDescription, double cost) {
    mItems.add(new MenuItem(itemDescription, cost));

}

public String getTableName() {
    return tableName;
}

public Amount getSubtotal() {
    double total = 0;
    for (MenuItem item : mItems) {
        total += item.cost.getRawValue();
    }

    return new Amount(total);
}

public void markAsSigned() {
    hasBeenSigned = true;
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public MenuItem getMenuItemAt(int index) {
    return mItems.get(index);
}}
```

Comment: How is "Check" integrated in your code? I don't see it in any of the activities.

Comment: it's not. I don't know how to integrate it

Comment: you wrode the check code i suppose, how did u write the code if you dont have any idea how to integrate it into your own code. Besides, to me it looks like 'DataStore.CHECKS' contains all available checks?

Comment: Check.java was written for me by my professor. I created the activities. I just don't know how to actually call it

Comment: so you are asking us to do your homework for you? :) To call it is pretty easy, just call getSubtotal() on a Check object. But first you will have to create a Check-Object and add some content to it, like different menus.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick hint: You are sending some data to the second activity via Intent (`onItemClick`). In the second activity in `onCreate`, you can pick this data and call your `getSubtotal` method. Since it's not quite clear, what "Check" does, it's up to you how to instantiate it:

```
public class PayCheckActivity extends Activity{ 
    // ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) {
            String value = intent.getStringExtra(PayCheckActivity.Extra_check);
            Check check = .....
            check.getSubtotal()
        }

    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you cant simply send an Object from one activity to another using intents, you would have to implement the Serializable interface for the class in order for this to work, seems much simpler to get the total first and then send that value to the second activity, assuming you dont need the whole check there.

Comment: @Danel-Bo You right. For me the question was more "how one can trigger something in some other activity based on some data from the calling activity". And since OP needs to figure out how to integrate the "Check" first, it makes no sense to go into details.

Comment: so would I put this method in the first activity instead?

Comment: @user3390870 As Daniel Bo suggested, it makes more sense to make all calculations in the first activity and send something which already is serializable (String, Integer, ...) with the intent to the second activity... but it's up to you.